# Convert double to zoned_time using Howard Hinnant's date library

Tags: c++, date, datetime

I have a double representing the time in days since midnight (local time zone) 1 Jan 1970 and a string representing the time zone. I would like to convert these to a
    date::zoned_time
using Howard Hinnant's date and time zone library.

The background is I need to convert date-times to and from doubles to use in an analytics library. I will also receive date-times as doubles from excel in a local or user-specified time zone.

Here is one attempt I made

```
using namespace date;
using namespace std::chrono;
typedef date::zoned_time<std::chrono::seconds> datetime;
const double UNIX_MINUS_EXCEL_EPOCH = 25569.0;
const double SECONDS_PER_DAY = 24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0;
datetime timePointFromDouble(double x)
{
    double seconds = (x - UNIX_MINUS_EXCEL_EPOCH) * SECONDS_PER_DAY;
    system_clock::duration d = duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(duration<double>(seconds));
    system_clock::time_point t = system_clock::time_point(d);
    auto xx = make_zoned("America/Chicago", t);

    return xx;
}
```

It doesn't compile because the result of make_zoned has the wrong type. Also, I am not convinced it correctly maps the input time in days to the output date-time because of leap seconds and days where daylight saving changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Specification:

- `x` is a measure of days since 1899-12-30 00:00:00 in America/Chicago.

### Solution:

```
using datetime = date::zoned_seconds;

datetime
timePointFromDouble(double x)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using ddays = duration<double, days::period>;
    constexpr auto excel_epoch = local_days{1_d/January/1970} -
                                 local_days{30_d/December/1899};
    return datetime{"America/Chicago",
             local_seconds{round<seconds>(ddays{x} - excel_epoch)}};
}
```

### Explanation:

The reason your version doesn't compile is because of the conversion to `system_clock::time_point`, which in practice has a precision of microseconds or finer.  But your result type has a precision of seconds, so the library is refusing to implicitly truncate your high-precision `t` to your lower-precision `xx`.

The easiest way to fix this is to `time_point_cast<seconds>(t)`.  But there's more fun to be had...

`<chrono>` lives and dies by handling the conversions for you.  Any time you're doing the conversions yourself, you should opt for removing those conversions in favor of letting `<chrono>` do them.  This will usually simplify your code, and it *may* just catch a conversion error.

`<chrono>` knows about how to convert among various durations, but not about the Excel epoch, so that's one conversion we can't avoid.  But we can express that epoch in a higher level language than the mysterious constant 25569.0.

So, from the top:

- `date::zoned_seconds` is a simpler way to write `date::zoned_time<std::chrono::seconds>`.  It is just a convenience typedef.
- `ddays` is a custom `duration` unit which represents 1 day with a `double`.  This is convenient for converting the scalar input `x` directly into a `<chrono>` duration.  It is best to get into the `<chrono>` type system as soon as possible.
- The epoch difference is the amount of time between 1970-01-01 and 1899-12-30.  The units will be days as I've coded it, but that is an unimportant detail.  `<chrono>` takes care of the units for you.
- I'm using `local_days` as opposed to `sys_days` to compute the epoch difference.  This is a largely symbolic gesture to communicate that the epoch is in a local time, not UTC.  It doesn't make a difference in the actual value of the constant that is computed.
- Because of the way you worded the question, I assumed you would prefer day-month-year ordering in the code.  This is a purely stylistic choice.
- If you are writing this in C++11, `excel_epoch` will have to be made `const` instead of `constexpr`.  The difference is that C++11 has to compute this constant at run-time and C++14 and later can compute it at compile-time.
- When converting from double-based units to integral-based units, I like to use `round` instead of `duration_cast`.  The difference is that `round` chooses the nearest representable value, and `duration_cast` truncates towards zero to the nearest representable value.  The `round` strategy is more likely to result in stable round-trip conversions between the double and integral representations, whereas truncation is more likely to expose one-off differences due to round-off error in the double representation.
- The last line has to explicitly get us from double-based to integral-based units, and has to specify `seconds` to match with the return type, but does not have to worry about converting days into seconds.
- The last line uses `local_seconds` to convert the `duration` into a `time_point` because this `duration` represents a measure in the *local* time of America/Chicago, as opposed to a measure in UTC.  This fixes the epoch to 1899-12-30 00:00:00 in America/Chicago as opposed to 1899-12-30 00:00:00 UTC.
- The result does not take leap seconds into account.  This is the correct thing to do, because neither does Excel nor `system_clock`.  Just about every computer-based time-keeping protocol out there doesn't count leap seconds.  Here is a good description of [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  If you want to convert to a system that counts leap seconds, this library can do that too.  It is called [`utc_clock`/`utc_time`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#utc_clock).
- The result does take daylight savings time into account for Chicago, including the changes to the daylight savings rules over the years, as best as the [IANA database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) can do (which is exact as far as I know).

Comment: I intended x to be a measure of days since 1899-12-31 00:00:00 America/Chicago, because excel works entirely in the user's local time zone. I have edited the question to reflect this. It would be very helpful if you could update your answer to reflect that. Meanwhile seconds was something I just introduced to try to get it to work and is not important to me. Thank you for such a helpful answer

Comment: There is probably a small adjustment to be made since excel incorrectly thinks 1900 is a leap year but that will be easy to handle myself

Comment: Ok, I've changed the epoch to be specified in America/Chicago.  I didn't know about that detail of Excel, thanks.

Comment: The fact that Excel treats 1900 as a leap year is taken care of with the 1899-12-31 epoch.  Excel claimed that the epoch is 1900-01-01 and that 1900 is a leap year.  That is equivalent to saying that the epoch is 1899-12-31 and 1900 is not a leap year.

Comment: The precision of the result can be easily changed by simply changing the precision of the return type (e.g. `zoned_time<milliseconds>`), and the precision in the `round` expression (e.g. `round<milliseconds>(...)`).  In C++14 the return type can be computed with `auto` so that you just have to specify the precision in two places in the return expression.  In C++17 CTAD will get that down to just one place in the return expression.  And in C++20, everything in namespace `date` moves into namespace `std::chrono`.

Comment: Thank you again for such a helpful answer. It's good to know how to change precision - I may need this before long

Comment: Finally it turns out, to overcome the excel 1900 issue, I had to use local_days{ day{30} / December / 1899 } instead of local_days{ last / December / 1899 }

Comment: You have taught me again! (thanks!).  I will update my answer to include your fix.